# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, bcrypt

While implementing what I thought was a simple `signup/login` system for a Ruby on Rails app, results haven't matched what tutorials have shown.

I'm trying to use bcrypt for authentication and PostgreSQL for the database.

I continually get '`ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name):` ', even though it will show name as being input. `'"users"=>{"name"=>"asdf", "password"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf", "password_confirmation"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"} (0.1ms)`

[output from the console when attempting to sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdfHc.png)

users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


def new
end

def create
  user = User.new(
    name: params[:name],
    password: params[:password],
    password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
  if user.save
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    redirect_to '/signup'
  end
end

private

end
```

The table

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


def new
end

def create
  user = User.new(
    name: params[:name],
    password: params[:password],
    password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
  if user.save
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    redirect_to '/signup'
  end
end

private

end
```

and the signup form

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


def new
end

def create
  user = User.new(
    name: params[:name],
    password: params[:password],
    password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
  if user.save
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    redirect_to '/signup'
  end
end

private

end
```

the user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


    PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
    (?=.{10,})          # Must contain 10 or more characters
    (?=.*\d)           # Must contain a digit
    (?=.*[a-z])        # Must contain a lower case character
    (?=.*[A-Z])        # Must contain an upper case character
    (?=.*[[:^alnum:]]) # Must contain a symbol
    /x

    #formatting for password

    USERNAME_FORMAT = /\A[a-z0-9A-Z\-_]{2,15}\z/ #Can contain lowercase and upercase letters, numbers, - and _, must be between 2 and 15 length

    #username formatting

    validates :name,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => true,
    :format => USERNAME_FORMAT

    validates :password, 
    :presence => true, 
    :format => PASSWORD_FORMAT,
    :confirmation => true, 
    :on  => create 

  has_secure_password
end
```

I've tried `troubleshooting`, all similar questions haven't yielded an answer or fix.

EDIT: More clarity on issue

Comment: Add `puts user.errors.full_messages` just before the `redirect_to '/signup'` in `create`. See what its printing in the terminal. It will tell you why the record is not persisting.

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20:in `user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `create'

Comment: So, that means that the value you are passing in for `name` is empty/invalid according to the validation.

Comment: Is there a suggested fix? Input isn't invalid and I'm at a loss for what to do.

Comment: According to your logs, you send this name to the controller: `"name"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf"`. But you have a regex validation on name and "Qq!1asdfasdf" don't pass `USERNAME_FORMAT`. Try with another name i think it should work.

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GPoKZ243mjrtwHFXCnX+3UDaWL5AUwGZHBwW3pFn+JEAQF6iQWriAR2/m7UIc96/cJFKS6n+pFnCgy6vOrHWCQ==", "users"=>{"name"=>"asdf", "password"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf", "password_confirmation"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 400 Bad Request in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name):

Even with correct input it still doesn't work, I've also removed the username regex for testing.

Comment: In that case, your regex for USERNAME_FORMAT might be wrong. Go test it out with something like https://regex101.com against the input you are testing with.

Comment: Even fully omitting the regex, as in no validation, I still get the errors.

EDIT: the above error code was with no validation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rails [**`Strong Parameter`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) like the following

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
      user = User.new(user_params)
      if user.save
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        redirect_to new_user_path
      end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

Comment: Still not getting there,
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xl6lwi1CGGcuZIxjkvQsWqGrQwqtruLg9FheiC1UNZze5PEHAh9gXN4bZoGQ8gw4keBR/0QDRyAqx2b5hoIbBA==", "users"=>{"name"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf", "password"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf", "password_confirmation"=>"Qq!1asdfasdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: The `name` input field not passing the value, you can check there,

Comment: I've checked but I don't know what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of passing data between your form and your controller.
In your logs your parameters for user looks like: `"users"=>{"name"=> ...}` but it should be `"user"`

To pass data between your controller and your view, you need to use instance variable such as `@user` to make the new instance of `User` available in the view. ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions))

In that way your controller should be:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    redirect_to '/signup'
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

(with strong parameters like @fool-dev explained)

Then in your view, use this `@user` to pass the parameters to the controller:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  //...the form
<% end %>
```